# How to power this RF microwave solid state switch

Tags: rf, switches, microwave, solid-state-devices

I have the following RF switch:

[image: MyRFswitch]

After googling for several hours, I have found that it is a solid state switch,
from DC to 26.5GHz.

I've also been able to test that between the golden plated female SMA connector to the silver plated one, there is a connection when the device is not energized, while there is no connection between the golden plated female connector and the male SMA connector (tested both with DC and a VNA.)

I've taken a risk, and tried to energize the unique pin (at the top) with up to 5V voltage from the ground, without any change in the above behavior. I've also measured the current flowing through the pin, and find that it increases non-linearly from 1mA at 1V, more or less doubling per each volt, up to about 10 mA at 5V. I've stopped here because I don't want to burn this expensive device.
I've sought for some hints about how to power the switch, but nothing more than this image:

[image: OtherRFswitch]

This is not exactly the same switch, but it may help. In particular, I would like to understand what they mean by +5V, -10V.

Comment: If it's a diode switch like the lower one is, you can't use it to switch DC; it can only switch RF. There's always a DC path through a diode from one side to the other.

Comment: @Hearth. thx for answering me. I have tested the connection with a VNA, not with DC. I will edit my question, since it is misleading about this point.

Comment: @Hearth , I agree, put it in the answer.

Comment: @jay I don't know enough about this to write up a proper answer, and the asker has clarified that it also does not switch RF under the conditions they tested, so it wouldn't be a correct answer anyway--it seems it's not a diode switch.

Comment: Oops. @Hearth, sorry about that. I will read the main text.

Comment: @jay It may not be clear to someone without some knowledge of RF test equipment, also--VNA stands for vector network analyzer, which is a very powerful tool but in this instance is merely being used as, essentially, a multimeter that can do continuity tests at RF.

Comment: Thanks @Hearth, I just faintly remembered, since I thought I would be able to automate the Smith chart, when I was at the college, while PDP4 was only available to computer class kids. H h..

Comment: @MikeTeX, I am still convinced it is likely a diode switch. The amount of the current you are seeing is too large, since it just biases diodes reverse.... wait, does forward bias for any reason? Anyway, a random thoughts, try -1V, not 1V, with a current limiting resistor in series (don't know how much), while monitoring the current.

Comment: @Jay. That's work! many thanks. You are right: a voltage of  -1 to -3 V do the switching between the two female pins. But now, I don't understand what is the function of the male pin: it remains closed all the time.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I feel blessed. :-) I will let @Hearth answer the rest, since I cannot fish out my too far away memories.

Comment: With that negative bias to switch, I suspect it's a JFET switch, and the current you saw before was forward-biasing the JFET's gate. But, since I know very little about RF, I don't feel comfortable answering in any sort of definitive way.

Answer (score 2):

I am now able to answer this question, as this can be useful for others (thx to @Jay and @Hearth for their comments).

The device switching pin should be powered by a negative voltage:
at 0V, the switch is closed.
At -3V, it is opened, that is, it attenuates the signal by 30db or so.
Between these limits, the device attenuates the signal accordingly. In particular, it could probably be used as a voltage controlled attenuator.

Note: the silver SMA jack is the COM terminal, the golden SMA jack passes frequencies from DC to 2.7 GHz from the COM, while the silver SMA plug passes frequencies from 2.5 GHz to at least 12 GHz (to 26.5 GHz according to some web sources). The switch connects and disconnects both terminals at once from the COM terminal (it does not switch from one terminal to the other).

Comment: Glad you got that figured out! Only 30 dB of attenuation seems like not very much, though; are you sure it's fully off at -3 volts, and doesn't require a lower voltage to be fully off?

Comment: @Hearth. Well, perhaps if I go to -5V, there will be a better isolation. Will take a risk and try it slowly when I am in my lab.

Comment: If you monitor the current on that pin, you should be able to turn it off before anything is damaged. A curve tracer would be nice for this, but I imagine you probably don't have one handy.

Comment: well, 30 dB of isolation for an PIN diode RF switch is a more-than-decent amount of isolation ;)